# How to decline participation in team building activities

Tags: relationships, work-life-balance, team-building

I have this situation where I can't figure out what to do. Big team building event is coming up and it is happening at place where my girlfriend loves to go few times at summer time, it is really beautiful place.

I asked person, who is responsible for event, if my girlfriend can come too. She kindly responded that budget is really limited for this event, and that it's limited to only company workforce only. So I ask about expenses for one person and asked if I can cover for my girlfriend. I got strange response saying that its not that person responsible has got anything against my girlfriend, but that it would be weird that she is there, even if she does not participate in activities. I just asked I would like to have her by my side while i am there, because i know that she loves that place. And I got again this weird response that I should spend more time with colleagues and not make any excuse to avoid that.

The thing is I am not making any excuses I just want that my girlfriend is besides me while we are there, I would participate in all activities and all. It just don't feel right that I would go without her to this place.

Last few month I have skipped some activities with my team and colleagues, because of personal projects. I really want to go but at the same time I don't want to if can't take my girlfriend with me. I feel like not going it would somehow damage my relationships with team members, because there will be some kind of game activity and I have been placed in on of the teams, so if I won't go there will be team without one member. But in the same time, I feel that if I go I will damage the lovely bond I have with my girlfriend, because we mostly go places together, especially if one of us really likes that place.

How could I resolve this without any damage to both sides?
I have few options, but I want to hear other people ideas and answers.

Comment: I like meeting family of my coworkers at events but the atmosphere has to be right for that. Teambuilding workshop doesn't sound like the right atmosphere to bring your girlfriend or spouse. Btw the excuse about the budget thing is nonsense. The organizer was probably trying to be indirect about telling you no.

Comment: If your girlfriend can't understand that it's out of your control, I would say that your relationship is already damaged.

Comment: i am not talking about not understanding, i am talking about me not wanting to go without her ;)

Comment: Curious what country this is?

Comment: As much as I personally dislike 'teambuilding exercises' and sympathise with you preferring to spend time with your girlfriend instead, I think you need to get over the idea that it's somehow weird for an employer to say that partners are not invited to internal corporate training sessions. It's not weird at all.

Comment: @RobM I think there are some important unstated variables.  If the OP has to give up his weekend for a "fun" work activity that his girlfriend is explicitly not invited to, then there is some cognitive dissonance.

Comment: @emory agreed. Also, if the OP is being asked to give up their own time unpaid to take part in these exercises then that validates my loathing of team building exercises and the people who advocate for them, but still, you either 'play the game' or you do not with these events, and 'playing the game' means attending without your partner. Believe me, I'm not defending the practice, in fact I think it's disgraceful that employers think this is OK, but it is what it is.

Comment: As someone who has organized some activities, private and professional I can completely understand why you can't bring your girlfriend: If someone starts bringing his girlfriend once, many others will only find it fair to bring their family - and you will have whole families with kids there, people will get calls and have to skip events to care about their family. And others will feel the peer pressure to bring their family...

Comment: Related: [Team building: should the families be invited?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/27132)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

> How could i resolve this without any damage to both sides?

You have been told that girlfriends are not invited to these events, so even if it's a really pretty place, and even if your girlfriend likes it a lot, stop asking if she can come along to this company event - you've already gotten your answer.

Instead, bring your girlfriend on your own time - perhaps immediately following the team-building event. Explain to her that this is a company event, not a family-and-friends event, and that you need to pay attention to the team building activities for a while. Find another time that works well for both of you where you can pay attention to her.

Separating work life from home life is something we all need to learn to do as we grow up and mature professionally. Use this event as an opportunity for both you and your girlfriend to learn how to accomplish that without damaging any bonds.

(As David Mulder points out in the comment below, some cultures separate work life from home life more than others. Based on what you wrote about your discussion with the activity coordinator, I'm assuming you work in a culture that permits such a separation.)

Comment: You could consider taking a day off (or the weekend if the team building even ends on a Friday and having your girlfriend come up then and the two of you staying on together for a day or two. So she isn't there for the team building event, but she comes after and you share some time together.

Comment: What HLGEM suggests is very common and the best way to deal with this: lots of people I know have been to company events, conferences etc in nice locations, then stayed a few extra days at their own expense in their own time being joined by family/partners. It's best for everyone: during the work event, you're focussed on work related matters or getting to know your colleagues, and during the time with your partner, you're focussed on enjoying time with them.

Comment: "Separating work life from home life is something we all need to learn to do as we grow up and mature professionally" That depends a lot on company culture and is not necessarily a thing to strife for, despite being popularized in western culture in recent periods.

Comment: I second being there for a few days on your own time. I took my wife recently on a weekend training event, and whilst it was manageable, it took a lot of effort and time to keep up both with her and the event. She spent a lot of time alone, and some time I might had free to enjoy the place and/or have a few drinks with people, had to go out in the nearest town just to entertain her.

Answer (score 46):

Team building activities are just that: **team** building activities. The idea is that you spend time with your team away from your normal office and work.

If you take along your girlfriend, you will change the dynamics heavily. You will spend time and attention on your girlfriend (otherwise, why bring her along?), so you will naturally spend less time and attention on your team.

Your employer is sponsoring this event, and this happens on company time (or should, at least). Who pays the piper calls the tune. Your employer is very much in the right if they want you to concentrate on the team during these activities. You twice call it "weird" when your contact person tries to gently hint at this. I suggest that you think about this attitude and try to change it.

In addition, you mention that you already skipped some team events. I recommend that you be *very* careful about the image you project at work. Do your best to communicate that your team is important to you - at least during work hours. Frankly, pressing this exact issue is not the best way to make a good impression along these lines.

Finally: I'd recommend that you take your girlfriend to this place some other time. This will be more fair to her, too, since that way you'll be able to concentrate on her, without having to divide your time and attention between your colleagues and your girlfriend.

Comment: Good answer. I understand what you are trying to tell. I am very good at what i do and i communicate a lot at work, just wanted to please everybody. Thanks for response :)

Comment: It may just be that the OP would be happier at a place that skews more toward "life" in work/life balance.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. However I wonder how much of this applies when the company schedules this team building events in your free time (eg. in a weekend)? Time that is usually spent with my spouse and not at work.

Comment: on company time? Rarely seen that. 95% or so of the "team building activities, attendance mandatory" I've encountered over the last 20 years were in private time. Scheduled either after office hours, during weekends, or people were forced to take time off to attend (companies here have that option, to schedule a number of days a year that employees have to take off from work that are deducted from your holiday allowance).

Comment: @jwenting My experience is almost entirely opposite. Almost all 'teambuilding' activities have been on company time. On rare occasions when not, they were also not mandatory.

Comment: @jwenting - curious what country that is in? In a similar 20 years (in Australia) I have never heard of a company even considering mandatory team-building activities outside of business hours. They know that if they tried, nobody would come!

Comment: @Carson63000 just make it understood that non-participation will reflect poorly on your performance review, meaning no raise, no promotions, and you're first in line to be laid off in the next cycle and see people turn up and fake a happy smile for the boss...

Comment: I know my employer can force me to take vacation time off at their convenience, but if they tried to make me use that time to attend a training event the organiser had better not be holding their breath waiting for me to show up, for their own sake!

Comment: @jwenting threats works fine if one person doesn't want to waste their weekend but everyone else is willing to. But like I said, where I come from, *nobody* will stand for crap like that. Again, I'd be curious to know what country you're in that such a situation is commonplace?

Answer (score 9):

A team building event is a professional event, however in a casual setting.

This is still "on-time", it can be either during official working hours, or outside working hours.

Although the location is different, the tone is more fun, and people behave in a more relaxed way.

However, don't confuse official teambuilding events with your own free time.  This is different from the occasions that you spend with your girlfriend, friends, and family, or with the times when you go for a beer with colleagues after work, which is also your own free time.

Not "doing your job" during the team building event could the same way end your career, as not "doing your job" in the office/workplace.

I recommend to be professional. Give your best the same way during the team building event as you would do in the office/workplace, independently from the location.

---

Note:
When significant others are welcome, this information is usually explicitly given. Like a business dinner where husband/wife are also required, or a fund raising event. However, these are still "part of the job", and family members are expected to behave accordingly - i.e. to support you in your work role.

Comment: This answer assumes that the event is during working hours. That may or may not be the case, as pointed out by others.

Comment: I didn't mean only office (working hours). This attitude for me is also valid when team building happens in the evening, the weekend, or when the team goes away for a week.

Comment: I would not mind having a "team building" of a weekend, but it is completely unacceptable I would be in an event a whole week away from my wife.

Comment: I have changed the text to reflect both working and non working hours.